# C++ How to add vector in a vector? vector.push_back( vector<> )?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm creating a 2d vector array of char as a class variable, but I'm having troubles of adding a vector into the vector< vector > array.

I'm running gcc with C++ 11 standard.

I tried using `vector< vector<char> > row(size, vector<char> );` but errors will show saying I did not define `size` and `vector<char>`. If I define it with `int size` and `vector<char> col` it will think it's a new function declaration since I'm putting it as a class variable.

So I use the usual method `vector< vector<char> > row;` and have a function to add another vector into it. So I use `this->row[i].push_back( vector<char> col);` but then an error saying `error: expected primary-expression before ‘col’` appears. I also tried to use just `this->row[i].push_back( vector<char> );` but the error is still there saying `error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’`. This might be dumb but I have no idea how to add a vector into a vector.

```
class Vector2d {
private:
  int size;
  vector< vector<char> > row;
public:
  void make2d();
};

void Vector2d::make2d() {
  for (int i = 0; i < this->size; i++) {
    this->row[i].push_back( vector<char> col );  // compile error here
    for (int j = 0; j < this->size; j++) {
      this->row[i][j];
    }
  }
  cout << "It works!" << endl;
}
```

I expect it to add the vector array into the vector array, and that I can use `row[i][j]` for the rest of the program. But it gives a compiler error saying `error: expected primary-expression before ‘col’` I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Unrelated: You may get better performance from a single `vector` of size `size*size` and a function that performs a 2D<->1D translation (`row * size + column`) because of better [spatial locality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) and fewer pointers to chase. [See this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301).

Comment: Plus the code is often much simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vector<char> col` is not a valid expression. It almost looks like a declaration of a variable (which is not what you need here), except it lacks a semicolon to complete the statement.

Furthermore, you cannot access `row[i]` until `row` actually contains at least `i` elements. `row[i].push_back` attempts to push a char element into a `std::vector<char>` that is the `i`th element of the vector of vectors (except you never created the `i`th element).

Given that in the following loop you appear to assume that the inserted vector should have `size` elements, here is how to insert a single vector of `size` elements into a vector of vectors:

```
row.push_back(std::vector<char>(size));
// or more simply
row.emplace_back(size);
```

If you would like to insert an empty vector instead, simply use:

```
row.emplace_back();
```

And here is how you can insert all `size` vectors of `size` elements in one go so that you can use `row[i][j]` for all `i` and `j` that are less than `size`:

```
row.resize(size, std::vector<char>(size));
```